# Determine row value OR select first blank cell in a row

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am exporting data from excel to a word table (11 rows 7 columns). I have written a macro to do this for me but I have come across a critical problem. The data I am entering comes from 3 different workbooks and each workbook goes into a different column in the table.  Although this data comes from 3 different workbooks, it is grouped together. The units are tested at 3 different temperatures, and the data from each temp. goes into the correlating column of the word table. Here is my current code

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()
Dim myfile, wdApp As New Word.Application, wDoc As Word.Document
'select truck report file
ChDrive "E:\"
ChDir "E:\WG\TVAL\"
myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for Document")
Dim i As Integer
'searches for row with "avg" then selects column E(avg of temperature mean) of that row.
i = Application.Match("Avg", Sheet1.Range("A1:A20"), 0)

'makes the file appear
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(myfile)

With wDoc
Dim oRow As Row
For Each oRow In wDoc.Tables(8).Rows
If Len(oRow.Range) = 16 Then
With oRow
  .Cells(1).Range.Text = "Performance Review"
  .Cells(2).Range.Text = Range("e" & i)
  .Cells(3).Range.Text = ""
  .Cells(4).Range.Text = ""
  .Cells(5).Range.Text = ""
End With
Exit For
End If
Next 
End With
wDoc.Save
End Sub
```

1. Opens file path and then allows user to select the desired file
2. Finds the value I want to copy/paste or type into the word table
3. In word, searches table for first blank row, then types “performance review” into column 1 and types the value I want into the corresponding column of the table. (theres a column for each temperature)
   This works great for the first value I add, but when I go to add the next two values it types into a new row when I want it to be in the same row as the first value entered. I know I need to change

   If Len(oRow.Range)=16 Then

But I do not know what value to change it to so that it enters data into the row that already has Cells(1) with “Performance Review” and Cells(2) with the value range, and for the 3rd temp Cells(3) would also have a value. 
The value for cells(2) will be something like 22.56. Cells(3) would be like 5.21 
For each temperature I was planning on running a different macro, but I would like them to be similar to:

```
Dim oRow As Row
For Each oRow In wDoc.Tables(8).Rows
If Len(oRow.Range) = 16 Then
With oRow
  .Cells(1).Range.Text = "Performance Review"
  .Cells(2).Range.Text = Range("e" & i)
  .Cells(3).Range.Text = ""
  .Cells(4).Range.Text = ""
  .Cells(5).Range.Text = ""
End With
```

So I want the first macro to take fill cells(1) and Cells(2), this I have already accomplished. The second macro I need only cells(3) to have data entered into it. And for the 3rd macro I need cells(4) to have the value entered into it. 
Essentially all I need to solve is how to determine the value of the rows once the previous values have been entered. 
Hopefully this makes sense, I have been doing vba for about a month so I am still fresh to it. If anyone needs additional information or screenshots of examples just let me know!
If someone sees what I am trying to do here and has a better way to solve my problem please share!
I was thinking maybe for the 2nd and 3rd macros I could search for the first blank cell in the table but I have not been able to find that!

P.S. With the 3rd macro, would like to include a line of code that will change the background color of the row to white

Comment: I'm sort of following, but the exact question isn't clear. Are you trying to save the Row information, somehow? What trigers each of the macros?

Comment: Okay I actually figured it out. My question was how to count the value of the row so I could change the If Len(oRow.Range)=# Then line of code. turns out I had forgotten to count the space between "Performance" and "Review". How can I show this question as solved?

Comment: Those of us with enough reputation can "vote to close" as a "not reproducible" problem. I'm still not sure I understand the question, for what it's worth. I've been asking myself whether oRow.Index is what you're looking for, though?

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/39512-find-last-non-empty-cell-moving-horizontally.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184